# How to display EULA to the user in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

When my iPhone application start, I want to display EULA to the user for the first time the app is launch. And provide only an "Accept" button for the user to continue.

Does anybody have any ideas or has anybody else achieved anything similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

iTunes Connect (the website you use to submit your app to the App Store) has a text box for a custom EULA. There's no need to present it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

One way that comes to mind is implementing the **UIAlertView** class with only one button labeled "Accept". Documentation and sample code can be found at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

This of course can present questions based on the length of your EULA. Another possible answer would be using a regular view controller that has only one button, again labeled "Accept" to perform the segue. I for one like the use of UIAlertView in this case as it seems to fit the intention of the class.

Comment: I actually voted up Jack Lawrence's comment as I was really concerned about presenting the EULA in-app in the first place for HIG concerns.

Comment: in many countries, EULAs, that are presented after purchasing, are ineffective. (note: I am not a lawyer — don't count on my informations. Ask a lawyer)